# Javascript, ajax timing issues

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a problem with calling 2 separate ajax functions. I have a loop that loops through all checkbox elements on the page then if they are checked it calls an ajax function that moves some data in my database. Then outside of the for loop i call another ajax function that goes to my database and pulls the results back to my ID element. I have had to name my httprequests differently so they dont fight, Both functions work but the one outside my loop goes to fast and doesnt pull the new/changed data. If i put an alert before this outside loop function it then works. I have also tried to use a setTimeout(myFunctio(), 3000) with no luck.

Here is my code.

```
    function ungroupContact(){
    group = document.getElementsByName("moveGroup")[0].value;
    for(i=0;i<=25;i++){
        if(document.getElementById('checkBox'+i)){
            if(document.getElementById('checkBox'+i).checked){
                var email = document.getElementById('checkBox'+i).value;
                moveContact(email, group);
            }
        }
    }
    //alert("hello");
    //setTimeout(alert("hello"),12000);
    groupList1(group);
}
```

This is my first time posting, sorry if this is noobish, currently studying my degree in computer science.

Thanks for any suggestion and/or help

Sorry i should have known to put up the ajax functions. I have used the layout from w3schools.

```
   function moveContact(email, group){
    if (email=="" || group=="") 
      {
      document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML="Something wrong was entered";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
    if (xmlhttp1.readyState==1 || xmlhttp1.readyState==2 || xmlhttp1.readyState==3)
        {
        document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML="<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading'> ";
        }

      if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp1.open("GET","core/moveContact.php?group="+group+"&email="+email,true);
    xmlhttp1.send();
    return;
}
```

Comment: it is because of the asynchronous nature of ajax requests, you need to wait till all the requests are finished to sent the last call

Comment: can you share the `moveContact` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep track of when the last `moveContact()` asynchronous ajax function is done and then (and only then), call `groupList1()`.

Since you have not disclosed the `moveContact()` code where the ajax calls are probably being done, we can't really recommend specifics on tracking them.  One simple technique is to set up a counter of pending ajax calls and in each success handler for the `moveContact()` ajax calls, check to see if the counter has now reached zero.  If so, you can then call `groupList1(group)`.

Assuming you added a completion callback to `moveContact()`, you could do it like this:

```
function ungroupContact(){
    group = document.getElementsByName("moveGroup")[0].value;
    var contactsRemaining = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=25;i++){
        if(document.getElementById('checkBox'+i)){
            if(document.getElementById('checkBox'+i).checked){
                ++contactsRemaining;
                var email = document.getElementById('checkBox'+i).value;
                moveContact(email, group, function() {
                    --contactsRemaining;
                    if (contactsRemaining === 0) {
                        groupList1(group);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}


function moveContact(email, group, fn){
    if (email=="" || group=="") {
      document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML="Something wrong was entered";
      return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else  {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp1.readyState==1 || xmlhttp1.readyState==2 || xmlhttp1.readyState==3) {
            document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML="<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading'> ";
        }

        if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
            // we are done now, so call the finish callback
            if (fn) {
               fn();
            }
        }
      }
    xmlhttp1.open("GET","core/moveContact.php?group="+group+"&email="+email,true);
    xmlhttp1.send();
    return;
}
```

Comment: but how do you know if the last moveContact() will be done after some of earlier calls?

Comment: @pawlakppp - see the code I added to my answer.  By "last moveContact()", I don't meet the last one you sent.  I mean that there are no other pending `moveContact()` requests - they have all completed.

Comment: @pawlakppp - Now that you've included `moveContact()` code, I showed you how to add a completion callback function to it.

Comment: i'm not the OP, just insterested in topic ;)

Comment: Hey there jfriend00 I was just wondering what the funtion() does and how the fn variable works, sorry if this is a stupid question. Thank you very much for the quick reply

Comment: @Carl - The `fn` argument to `moveContact()` is a callback function that `moveContact()` calls when that contact is done being moved.  You can see in my version of `moveContact()` where `fn()` is called.  The caller of `moveContact()` passes an inline anonymous function as that third argument to `moveContact()`.  If you don't know what an inline anonymous javascript function declaration is, Google will help you way more than I can in a comment here.

Comment: Thanks again jfriend00. I have it working now but its a variation of your code as my alerts were showing increments of contactsRemaining variable and on 1 decrement. Is there a way i can show you what i have changed? or should i edit my code at the bottom to show how i changed it?
Thanks again and i will google up inline anonymous funtion. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Carl - you should use `console.log()` to track things because `alert()` will alter the async behavior because it pauses execution while `console.log()` does not.

Answer (score -1):

You can add callback function on success and in that function execute `groupList1` function when all methods finish executing:

```
var finished = 0;
moveContact(email, group, function() {
   if (++finished == 25) {
       groupList1(group);
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work because there's an `if` statement inside the `for` loop and there aren't necessarily 25 `moveContact()` calls.